# Deallocating object while in background thread

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading, dealloc

I have been working on iOS project, which used data downloading in background. Well, honestly say - implementation wasn't the best one (and was changed later to remove such nonobvious pattern), and I've got some problems with not-deallocated objects, and can't say, that docs gave me a clear understanding of what's going on. Code, demonstrating common idea:

```
- (void)loadModelAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    Model *model = [self modelAtIndex:index];
    if (model) {
        model.index = index;
        [self performSelectorInBackgroundThread:@selector(loadModelInBackgroundThread) withObject:model]
    }
}

- (void)loadModelInBackgroundThread:(Model *)model {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    model.data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:model.url];
    //and some other changes can be here
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(modelDidLoad) withObject:model waitUntilDone:NO]'
    [pool drain];
}

- (void)modelDidLoad:(Model *)model {
    [self saveModel:model atIndex:model.index];
    [self loadModelAtIndex:model.index + 1];
}
```

Well, almost all time it has been working as expected. Except if caller has beed deallocated while downloading in background - Model object stayed in memory, without being released (I've got growing memory at this point).

Can anyone explain me, what will happen in case of deallocation, while background thread is running? I'm not sure this code can be suitable at all, but still interested. Any modification will make things run well?

Answer (score 2):

> Except if caller has beed deallocated while downloading in background - Model object stayed in memory

the `performSelector | …Thread…` calls retain their arguments. If your objects are deallocated in that time, the problem lies elsewhere. Run with zombies enabled to locate it - you can record every reference count.

Comment: Because the last piece of code that release the object would be the internal thread management itself, we might also need to temporarily comment out the `performSelectorInBackground` line to be able to detect over releasing.

Comment: @tia Instruments records every reference count op for you (if requested), with backtraces. that's sufficient for most uses. The only real issue I see would be ensuring the caller is deallocated from the main thread if it holds UIKit references (or *something* which must operate on the main thread). That, however, is a separate problem - the OP's dealing with a zombie: "caller has beed deallocated while downloading in background"